# sudo without sudo, implying sudo in script

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, bashrc, function

I made some scripts containing some functions which by design needs sudo permission. I have added those path in `.bashrc` for `Linux` and `.bash_profile` for `MacOS` so that it can be called from anywhere.

But I do not want the user to type `sudo` each time they want to call those script functions. Is there any way I can imply `sudo` in a way that whenever these functions are called, terminal would assume its being called from root user?

I think I should just add `sudo -i` at the beginning of the script or maybe each function? Or is there any other alternative way of implying `sudo`? Also, would be great to know if you think it would be terrible or dangerous to imply sudo and if it is not recommended.

An example of `dangerous-function` script that contains some functions which, I am trying to accomplish without specifying `sudo`

```
#!/bin/bash
start-one()
{
    ## do dangerous stuff with sudo
    systemctl start dangerous.service
}

start-two()
{
    systemctl start dangerous1.service
}

start-launchwizard()
{
    systemctl start dangerous2.service
}

## Calling functions one by one...
"$@"
```

I dont want to call them by `sudo dangerous-function start-one`
I just want to call them with `dangerous-function start-one` but still get the same result as the previous one.

Comment: Why can't you execute the script like `$ sudo ./script.sh`?

Comment: @0xSheepdog Thank you. I have updated the question. I dont know, just want to try I guess.

Comment: Why don't you just add sudo to the function? `start_one() { sudo systemctl ...` ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, because if I want to make a systemd service for my script, including sudo within the script becomes weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"$@"` will expand to the list of command line arguments, individually quoted.  This means that if you call your script with

```
./script.sh start-one
```

it will run `start-one` at that point (which is your function).  It *also* means that invoking it as

```
./script.sh ls
```

it would run `ls`.

Allowing a user to invoke the script using `sudo` (or using `sudo` inside the script) would allow them to run any command as root, if they had `sudo` access.  You do not want this.

Instead, you would need to carefully validate the command line arguments.  Maybe something like

```
foo_func () {
    # stuff
    printf 'foo:\t%s\n' "$@"
}

bar_func () {
    # stuff
    printf 'bar:\t%s\n' "$@"
}

arg=$1
shift

case $arg in
    foo)
        foo_func "$@" ;;
    bar)
        bar_func "$@" ;;
    *)
        printf 'invalid sub-command: %s\n' "$arg" >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

Testing:

```
$ sh script.sh bar 1 2 3
bar:    1
bar:    2
bar:    3
```

```
$ sh script.sh baz
invalid sub-command: baz
```

This would be *safer* to use with `sudo`, but you would still not want to execute anything that the user gives you within your various functions *directly* without sanitising the input. The script above does this by restricting the user to a particular set of sub-commands, and each function that handles a sub-command does *not* execute, `eval`, or `source` its arguments.

Let me say that again with other words: *The script does not, and should not, try to execute the user input as code in any way*. It should not try to figure out whether an argument corresponds to a function in the current environment that it can execute (functions may have been put there by the calling environment) and it should not execute scripts whose pathnames were given on the command line etc.

If a script is performing administrative tasks, I would be expecting to have to run it with `sudo`, and I would not want *the script itself* to ask me for my password, especially not if it's a script that I may want to run non-interactively (e.g. from a cron job).  That is, a script performing administrative tasks requiring root privileges should (IMHO) be able to *assume* it's running with the correct privileges from the start.

If you want to *test* this in the script, you could do so with

```
if [ "$( id -u )" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'please run this script as root' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

It then moves the decision of *how* to run the script with root privileges to the user of the script.

Comment: Wow, this was explained so perfectly. I will implement this case statement to avoid inputting invalid commands. Also, I was feeling the same way as you about implying sudo, and giving prompt to user if run without sudo would be much better, but I think I will still try to imply sudo after I sanitize the input from user. :)

Comment: @RakibFiha Note that you can't easily use `sudo` with functions (if you need to do that). See e.g. [Executing a Bash Script Function with Sudo](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/269078)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I am trying to figure out how can I check if the parameter passed exists as a function from an array as Im trying to implement your case statement.

Comment: @RakibFiha Note that you don't need to do that as you can simple switch through the _valid_ cases, and output an error when none matches. The point is that you _don't_ use the string given to you by the user as something you can call. Instead you use that string to figure out if it's a sting that is valid. It's very much like testing the command line options (`-h`, `-a` etc.) to see whether a given option is valid or not.

Comment: the case statement is working like a charm now, but I wanted to make a hash table because now my number of functions are increasing and did not want to write case statement for every single function one by one. For some reason case statement is worked only for the first object of the array. Thank you again. Learnt alot from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your script in `/etc/sudoers` (preferably using `visudo) so that it is accessible to the user.

```
user ALL= /path/to/script
```

Then the user will able to execute `path/to/script` without sudo.

Comment: Note that since the script simply executes `"$@"`, this would allow the user to execute anything with root privileges, e.g. `sudo /path/to/script reboot`.

Comment: @Kusalananda wow, thank you for pointing that out. I thought $@ was only passing the functions within the script. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Adding a script to `sudoers` doesn't make it magically run without needing `sudo`. It simply tells the `sudo` command it's allowed to let the user run that script. You still need to invoke `sudo`.